# iOS swift: dynamic function graph/chart

Tags: ios, swift, graph, charts

I'm trying to understand how I could make a graph / chart of a function, with different gradient colors. Something like the image below.

Basically my coordinates change almost daily so I need something very reusable.

I know that there isn't any iOS framework, do you know any technique?

[image]

Comment: Use canvas 2d tech .

Comment: @NikolaLukic what do you mean? Core Graphic?

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/87899/make-simple-drawing-app-uikit-swift  Here's you have even download project link . Almost every client languages have standard UI design and little more complicated canvas 2d and also 3d . The principle is always the same .

Comment: yes, but the problem would be the gradients

Comment: No , in draw loop create some object who will return color (just like you want to be). Use draw1PxStroke with always updated parameters . Effect around dots -> If you background is always white draw small circle with stroke  color = white .

Answer (score 0):

You can define for every Pixel line parameters like width , color and position .

Create Common.m:

```
void draw1PxStroke(CGContextRef context, CGPoint startPoint, CGPoint endPoint, CGColorRef color);
```

...

```
void draw1PxStroke(CGContextRef context, CGPoint startPoint, CGPoint endPoint, CGColorRef color) 
{
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapSquare);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, startPoint.x + 0.5, startPoint.y + 0.5);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, endPoint.x + 0.5, endPoint.y + 0.5);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);           
}
```

Look more data at this post :

[See More Link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/32283/core-graphics-tutorial-lines-rectangles-and-gradients)